# Keep the same Ubuntu boot screen while keeping a desktop package

Tags: 10.04, gnome, kubuntu, xubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.04 .

Just after installing Ubuntu, I installed all the desktop packages except lubuntu.

Then when I restarted the computer, Ubuntu shows the Kubuntu boot screen when I restart the computer.

Next I uninstalled all the desktop packages except ubuntu-desktop.  The boot screen changed back to the Ubuntu one.

So how can I retain the Ubuntu boot screen while keeping the other desktop packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

Then it will ask you to choose the default login manager. Use `TAB` to move between options.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that change the login manager, rather than the boot screen?

Comment: Apparently. Use `sudo update-alternatives --set default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth`.

Comment: Does it work in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Yes. However, it might help to do a `sudo update-initramfs -a` to tell the initial ramdisk about the change.

Comment: What do you mean?  Sorry I am not very familiar with the terminal.

Comment: If you don't update the initial ramdisk with the plymouth theme, it may shutdown with your selection but with the old selection until the kernel is updated. I also made a small typo; the correct command is  `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Another hint is to install the `galternatives` if you want to graphically switch between themes.